# Javascript parsing remote xml with &signs

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I want to parse xml responses from www.digiflora.se. But some of the text between tags contains the &-sign which stops the parser.

Since it is not my server, I cannot change the resulting XML. And I cannot replace as part of the parsing since the error occurs too early in the process.

When debugging this I also get confused by the cross-domain restriction in Chrome (which some say also extends to locally stored files). But I think the below example shows that this has nothing to do with that.

I pasted some of the problematic text into a w3shools example.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note>
<to>Urvalslista f&ouml;r &ouml;rter och ris. &nbsp;&nbsp;</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Javascript/jquery

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "note.xml",
dataType: "html",
success: function(xml) {
$.parseXML( xml);
}
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note>
<to>Urvalslista f&ouml;r &ouml;rter och ris. &nbsp;&nbsp;</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
jquery-1.10.2.js:516
```

---

Continuation: A more general version of the question: I experimented with 2 files. exampleWithoutAND.xml , exampleWithAND.xml . When I try the one WITH &-sign, I see no popup. When I try the one WITHOUT the &-sign, I see the popup. Why?

exampleWithoutAND.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note>
<to>Urvalslista </to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

exampleWithAND.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Urvalslista & </to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And the full javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery and XML</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="language" content="en" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
</head>

<body
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType: "xml",
        //url: "exampleWithoutAND.xml",
        url: "exampleWithAND.xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          alert("!");
        }
      });
     });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you set up jsFiddle?

Comment: Never tried it before. Where do I put the xml file?

Comment: I answered below. Try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change datatype to `xml`. You don't need to parse it.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "svfxml.php.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
       alert($(xml).find("title").text())
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that back. Changing 'html' to 'xml' does not work. I cannot execute anything inside the success: function (xml) {} if there are &-characters in the xml-file.

Comment: it works for me. I update my answer to retrieve title which has lot of &. It return "Urvalslista f&ouml;r &ouml;rter och ris. &nbsp;&nbsp;" for me.

Comment: I just put an alert("!"); and nothing else inside the success function. It works (in firefox) if not &'s but not at all if i just add one &

Comment: It works for me. What errors are you getting? Without your help it's hard to say.

Comment: Or setup example somewhere.

Comment: Firefox says "not well-formed note.xml3"

Comment: Then you should have wrong xml. I Update my answer again. I save xml from this [url](http://digiflora.se/seek/svfxml.php??uiset=1). In that title has &. It works for me. & is not at all a problem.

Comment: save that link as "svfxml.php.xml" in your index.html file folder and try. Are you new to jquery?

Comment: It works!!! Will now try to understand why. Then most likely I will get back here with more questions :)

Comment: Thanks. It helped in that I see now that I can parse the actual files. But I still do not understand why my small example files cannot be parsed if they have &s in them.